# Position of whatever

Tags: exam-questions

> Do not try in your home whatever you see here.

Is the sentence correct grammatically?Otherwise, how to use to speak such type of sentence?

Comment: “Don’t try this at home” is a very well known fixed phrase.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the *syntax* but the semantics are slightly unclear.

What if what you see is a box? It wouldn't make sense to *try a box* at home.

To make it clear that what you see is an *action* that's being performed, it would be better to add something more to the sentence:

> Do not try in your home whatever you see *being done* here.

In this way, there can't be any confusion over seeing something that can't *be done*—simply because you are seeing somebody doing it.

---

There is nothing wrong with the use of *whatever*. But, having said that, the overall sentence might sound better if you reverse the components:

> Whatever you see being done here, do not try it in your home.

However, that's just a matter of personal opinion. The original is fine—with the one changed I made.